# Installing boost_date_time in mac

Tags: c++, boost, osx-snow-leopard

How do in install boost_date_time in mac? i used macport to install boost. But it did not install date_time. Then i tried installing using the binary downloaded from boost website. using

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=path/to/installation/prefix --with-libraries=library-name-list
```

but still the compilation fails

```
g++ -o test -g -O2  -I/usr/include/mysql test.cpp -lz  -lz  -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lboost_date_time-mt >&5
ld: library not found for -lboost_date_time-mt
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacPorts installs headers and libs in `/opt/local/include` and `/opt/local/lib`.

So, you would need to add the following parameters:

```
-I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib
```

The bootstrap script is used to build `bjam`, the boost build tool. It's not necessary if you installed from MacPorts.

Comment: these are my $PATH dirs : /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/include:/opt/local/lib:/usr/local:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't believe GCC uses $PATH to find headers or libraries.